# C#: No casting within Generics?

Tags: c#, generics, casting

While I can upcast a string to an object, I cannot upcast an IList of strings to an IList of objects. How come? What to do now other that coping all items to a new IList?

```
static void ThisWorks()
{
     IList<object> list = new List<object>();
     list.Add("I can add a string since string : object");
}

static void ThisDoesNotWork()
{
     // throws an invalid cast exception
     IList<object> list = (IList<object>) new List<string>(); 

     list.Add("I'm never getting here ... why?");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at it like this: while a banana is a fruit, a basket of bananas is not a basket of fruit, since you can add oranges to the latter, but not the former. Your `List<string>` has stronger constraints than a `List<object>`.

Casting should always respect [Liskow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). For containers and iterators which do not admit modification, such casting is safe, but once things can be changed, you are skating close to the thin ice.

Comment: This does respect LSP: he's treating a *more* derived type (string) as a *less* derived type (object). In general, this is supposed to be safe.

Comment: Nope. He's trying to make a fruit basket out of a banana basket. As long as he's only doing reads it's safe, but things get strange if non-strings are added.

Comment: In fact, this could be possible in some cases -like C# 4.0 that will support **safe** generic co/contravariance-, so your example is not entirely true.

Comment: And also, arrays has supported variance since the first release of Microsoft .NET Framework. You can cast Orange[] to Fruit[].

Comment: @Pontus: That's the point. The act of treating a basket of Bananas as a basket of Fruit is just fine from a type theory perspective. It shouldn't cause an exception, but it does because generics are invariant.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Array covariance isn't safe, actually for the reason that Pontus points out. You can add an Apple to a Fruit[] at compile time, but that's not safely covariant.

Comment: It's not safe, but nevertheless it is. I have not fundamental problem with the answer. It's correct. I just wanted to point out that the example can be misleading in some cases.

Comment: @everyone: Thanks for your help. I actually asked two questions -- sorry --, still I have to choose a single answer. I feel that reading this answer WITH all the comments will make a pretty good answer for anyone finding the question in google. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

This is not possible as generics are invariant (as of C# 3.0).

You can workaround it with:

```
var objectList = list.Cast<object>().ToList();
```

Comment: I think you mean to say that generics *are* invariant. They're not *covariant*. They will be in C# 4, though.

Comment: @John: Even in C# 4 only certain things will be covariant. In particular, classes can't be variant - only delegates and interfaces.

Comment: Jon: It was my fault. I incorrectly wrote "are not invariant" and John was pointing that mistake in the sentence :)

Comment: @Jon: You're right. But in this case you could treat the List<T> like an IList<in T> and get the same effect. The general operation he wants (add a more derived entry to a less derived list) would now be legal.

Answer (score 4):

What you asked is essentially a question of **Contravariance and Covariance**. It is a concept in programming language design which talks about how methods and collections behave with respect to objects of two classes in the same inheritance hierarchy. Reading the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) may help place your above curiosity in a larger, more general perspective.

Answer (score 2):

`string` inherits from `object` but `IList<string>` does not inherit from `IList<object>` they are unrelated types and therefor you can't cast between them.

Just think what would happen if this worked:

```
// THIS CODE DOES NOT WORK
IList<object> list = new List<string>(); // this doesn't compile
list.Add(5); // because this is perfectly valid on IList<object> but not on IList<string>
```